# Places offering samatha retreats / training

Tags: meditation-concentration, samatha, retreat

I'm looking for a place to train in samatha. I want to master jhana and time is not an issue. I can also do volunteer work in exchange for training. Any recommendations?

Comment: Where are you located and how far are you willing to travel?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Pa-auk Forest Monastery](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/) in Myanmar (Burma). A good friend just spent a year there. He did a fair amount of research before settling for Myanmar and he also spent months in a temple in Thailand beforehand. According to him, various monks from Korea as well as Sri Lanka, etc. go to Myanmar thinking that qualified Dharma teachers are difficult to come by in their countries. It seems likes "The place to be." He also said that "Most practitioners require between three and eight years of dedicated effort to obtain the full set of jhanas."

I do not know much about Pa-Auk though. For instance, I do not know whether they train lay people as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in coming to Ontario, Canada, this place - [Tisarana Buddhist Monastery in Perth, Ontario](https://tisarana.ca/), is the place for you. You can stay up to 3 months. You do not have to pay anything, but may have to do some volunteer work every other day. If you call them, it will be a person like you who will answer and give you all necessary details.  It is near Ottawa – the Capital City of Canada. I was there just two months ago. They have a very good library. Any bhikku will be of help to you while there. You can [take a look into their FB Page too,](https://www.facebook.com/pg/TBBKK/photos/?tab=album&album_id=358216725068) if you like - as it will give you a better idea.

The monastery is a residence for Buddhist monks and those who wish to train as Buddhist monks. Presently there are 20 monks, and 4 'anagaarika's (trainee monks). It is a retreat for those  interested who may visit for varying periods of time.